# Error : java program not printing output, calculation of cycle length

Tags: java, arrays, execution

I wrote a Java program which is used to calculate the largest cycle in different cycles of integers. but my code is taking input and not giving any output.. i have to print the largest cycle length from 1 to a given input integer i...and the largest cycle length along with time taken for execution are to be displayed..PLEASE CHECK and HELP.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class asgn {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    long i, j, n, max = 0, pos = 0, x, y;
    long count = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the positive integer:");
    while (sc.hasNextLong()) {
        x = System.currentTimeMillis();
        i = sc.nextLong();
        long arr[] = new long[50000000];
        for (long p = i / 2; p < i; p++) {
            arr[(int) p] = 0;
        }
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            n = j;
            while (n != 1) {
                count = 0;
            }
            {
                while (n < 50000000) {
                    if (arr[(int) (n - 1)] != 0) {
                        count = count + arr[(int) (n - 1)];
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (n % 2 == 0) {
                    n = n / 2;
                    count++;
                } else {
                    n = (3 * n) + 1;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (j < 50000000) {
                arr[(int) (j - 1)] = count;
            }
            if (count > max) {
                max = count;
                pos = j;
            }
            count = 0;
        }
        y = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Maximum cycle length occurs at " + pos + " and the number of steps involved  " + max + "\n Total time taken is " + (y - x) + "ms");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the error exactly? Have you tried to debug yourself already?

Comment: And *please* format your code - it's very, very hard to read at the moment.

Comment: @shree.pat18 there is no error, it asks me to enter the input, then for example i enter 100, it just stops like that, and nothing happens...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is stucked in the infinite loop from this while loop.

```
            while (n < 50000000) {
                if (arr[(int) (n - 1)] != 0) {
                    count = count + arr[(int) (n - 1)];
                    break;
                }
            }
```

n is never be greater 50000000 & your arr array is always 0.